# Given a measurable vector field, construct another such that together they form a basis at every point

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, differential-geometry

Let $v_1:(0,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ a measurable function such that $v_1(x)\neq 0$ for all $x$.

I wonder if it is possible to construct a measurable function $v_2:(0,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\{ v_1(x),v_2(x)\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Surely you could just take $v_2(x)\equiv(v_1^1(x),v_1^2(x))$, where $v_1^j$ are just the components of $v_1$? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Drat, I mistyped it and can't edit. I meant $(v_1^2(x),-v_1^1(x))$. Swap the components and negate one of them, so the result is perpendicular to the original.

Comment: This right, and in the case of $\mathbb{R}^3$ with $v_1,v_2$ as gender $v_3$ ?

Comment: I think you're asking what to do in the analogous case where you are given $v_1,v_2\in \mathbb R^3$ and want to find $v_3$ with analogous properties (assuming $v_1,v_2$ span a 2-dimensional space). Then just take $v_3 =v_1\times v_2$ (the cross product, which is perpendicular to both of the factors).

Comment: There is way to generalize for $v_1,...v_k$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$ ?

Comment: Take $v_2(x) = (-[v_1(x)]_2 , [v_1(x)]_1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple way to do this in general. For every $x$, let $i(x)$ be the smallest index such that the $i$th component of $v_1(x)$ is nonzero. Then define the other $(n-1)$ fields at $x$ to be $e_j$, $j\ne i(x)$. (Here $e_j$ are the standard basis vectors.)

To check  measurability, it suffices to show that $i(x)$ is a measurable function, which is straightforward.

Comment: Honestly a very interesting construction. It may get some explicit expression of the fields ?

Comment: @helmonio Some explicit expressions are in comments to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an 'explicit' construction for $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Suppose $v_k:(0,1) \to \mathbb{R}^n$, for $k=1,..,n-1$ are such that the $v_k$ are  measurable for all $k$, and for any $t$, the vectors $v_k(t)$ are linearly independent.

Let $\phi: (0,1) \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by
$\phi(t, x) = \det \begin{bmatrix} v_1(t) & \cdots & v_{n-1}(t) & x \end{bmatrix}$. Define $v_n(t) = (\phi(t,e_1),...,\phi(t,e_n))$, and note that
$\phi(t,x) = \langle x, v_n(t) \rangle$. It should be clear that for a fixed $x$, the function $t \mapsto \phi(t,x)$ is measurable, and hence $v_n$ is measurable.

Since the $v_k(t)$, for $k=1,...,n-1$, are linearly independent, we can choose some $w$ such that
$v_1(t),...,v_{n-1}(t), w$ forms a basis, and hence $\phi(t,w) \neq 0$. In particular, this tells us that $v_n(t) \neq 0$, and since
$\phi(t,v_n(t)) = \|v_n(t)\|^2 >0$, we see that for any $t$, the vectors $v_1(t),...,v_n(t)$ form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$.